# What does this vcl_hash function do?

Tags: wordpress, varnish, varnish-vcl

In several Varnish VCL examples for wordpress, I see the following:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  # Add the browser cookie only if a WordPress cookie found.
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wp-postpass_|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID") {
    hash_data (req.http.Cookie);
  }
}
```

Could someone please explain what this does? I have tried googling it but I don't follow.

I want to make sure it's not possible that someone could just create a cookie with some junk in it and call it `PHPSESSID` or something, and then magically it would think they're logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This checks to see if the user has a cookie named one of those (each `|` is the regex OR operator, so it can match any one of those). If there is a cookie with that name, then we hash the value of the cookie so that user gets their own cache. This is achieved using the `hash_data` function which adds the parameter to the cache key for the request (so you're adding the contents of `req.http.Cookie` to the cache key).

The reason for this is so logged in users don't see a cached version of the page from a logged out user.

This is pretty secure, although I personally wouldn't do this as it does open up some problems (e.g. a user logs out and invalidates their session, but an attacker could see the cached pages from say their profile page by replicating the request headers).

A better option is to simply not cache those pages (100% safe). You could put that in the `vcl_recv` function:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wp-postpass_|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID") {
    return (pass);
  }
}
```

Comment: ah-ha! I was really wondering that... I have exactly that code you put in my `vcl_recv`. So youre saying as long as i pass 100% of the time in recv i DONT need any code at all in vcl_hash?

Comment: Exactly, if you have `return (pass)` in the `vcl_recv` function, `vcl_hash` isn't even used (its only used when fetching/storing items in the cache)